# Why does Jet A currently cost roughly the same as 100LL?

Tags: cost, avgas, jet-fuel

I thought Jet A was substantially cheaper than 100LL but I recently looked at the prices throughout my area, and they are both priced at approximately $5.50 per gallon. I've never flown an aircraft that uses Jet A so I've never really paid attention, but I could have sworn that it was much cheaper than the leaded 100LL.

I can't find any articles or information online as to why Jet A is as expensive as 100LL. Avgas or 100LL is a specialty fuel and the only leaded fuel that is still made, so that explains why it is expensive, but Jet A is ubiquitous and produced in large quantity.

This previous [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/38002/why-is-jet-fuel-cheaper-than-piston-fuel) suggests the same thing that I'm saying, that Jet-A is cheaper because 100LL is a specialty fuel produced in small quantity, and Jet-A is widely available, etc. So, what has changed in the last 2 years?  It can't just be supply and demand.

Comment: Why _can't_ it just be (local) supply and demand?

Comment: Taxation can distort the apparent price of fuel. Airlines can reclaim much of the fuel tax they pay on international flights.

Comment: Is it possible that Jet-A has been subjected to the same sort of low sulfur regulations that has made diesel almost as expensive as gasoline for cars?

Comment: @Sean there doesn't seem to have been any major disruptions in supply, and on the demand side, if anything, the groundings of the 737 Max have slightly reduced demand. But I'm not an industry insider so these are just superficial observations. I'm hoping to hear from someone who has actual knowledge of this issue. Also, Its not just local, I looked at prices across the country on sky vector and it appears to be wide spread.